# Dropdown box with mysql connection

Tags: php, mysql, dropdownbox

I want to make 2 dropdownbox showing category and subcategory .

Category table in mysql has: catid, catname, description

Primary key is `catid`.

`Subcategory` table in mysql has subcatid, cname, subcatname

Primary key is `subcatid`, foreign key is `cname`

1st dropdownbox is able to retrieve `catname` from mysql table using php code..

Now, I want to retrieve subcategorynames , i.e. cname column in another dropdownbox

Depending upon category selected in first dropdownbox before submitting ...

In simple words:  if category selected in 1st dropdown is **ELECTRONICS** then subcategories available in 2nd Dropdownbox should be  Mobile TV....

if category selected in 1st dropdown is **AUTOMOBILES** then subcategories available in 2nd Dropdownbox should be  Tyres etc....

Retrieved from database..

I don't want to use ajax/js/jquery

Comment: if that is what you want to do, you do not really have a choice. Ajax/Js is pretty much mandatory, unless you want to reload the page everytime the dropdown is changed, but that is not very user friendly

Answer (score 1):

The only option you have if you do not want to use ajax/js is to reload the page/use iframe
So something like

```
<form method="get" action="index.php">
<select name="category">
<options>...</options>
</select>
<select name="subcategory">
</select>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Wiithout JS you cannot even submit the form using the onchange event so need to use a submit button.

However I would highly recommend against this as this is not userfriendly at all in this day in age of ajax. Please reconsider your requirements and use AJAX, or at very least javascript

Comment: this one is working in case of showing category, but how to code when 2nd dropdownbox should show the values selected on 1st dropdownbox

Comment: Well when you submit the form you are going to have to do a query SELECT id, name FROM category WHERE id = $_GET['category']

Comment: i want before submitting eg if person selects category electronics from dropdownbox1 then in dropdownbox2 subcategory of electronics should be shown then person perform submit work.. does $_GET  will work here?